# Struct is not visible to .cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, struct, visibility

I declared a struct at header file, you can see it below.

```
private: 
    struct Node{
        Customer data;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
    };
Node* find (const int index) const;
```

And declared a function that returns `Node*` private.

However when I try to implement the function `find` at my cpp file, it gives an error saying that "**identifier Node is undefined**".

```
Node* CustomerList::find(const int index){
    //some random code
}
```

What is the problem, isn't `Node` supposed to be visible to the .cpp ?

Comment: What class is `Node` declared in? You need `TheClassName::Node* ...`,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `CustomerList` is the class containing `Node`.

```
CustomerList::Node* CustomerList::find(const int index){
    //some random code
}
```

Within a `CustomerList` method you can just say `Node` but the return type is different, you still need to qualify with `CustomerList::`